# How to run sample github project that is has a single html and a typescript file? This should not be so difficult

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to try out the following library without writing code from this repo. 
https://github.com/pleerock/ngx-tooltip

I see the example is in a "sample" directory with an html and a ts file. I would usually just run a simple httpserver if it was a js and try to hit the html file in the browser, but this doesnt work because of the typescript file.

What is the right way/simplest way to run the sample in the directory in my webbrowser? I've already run npm install.

Comment: You will need to compile the typescript file into javascript file, because browser only recognise javascript and not typescript

Comment: Is there some simple command that could be run that starts the webserver and automatically compiles the typescript file? Usualy with python I just python -m SimpleHttpServer and try the example..

Comment: really depends on your set up. You will need the typescript compiler for sure. easiest way is to compile the `.ts` into `.js` and serve the js file and your html together with your SimpleHttpServer

Comment: Npm has a [lite-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server) that you can install, and then add its activation to an npm run script so that running `npm run dev` will load up the server. If you want to do it all in one command you can have the run script line in the package.json chain the tsc and lite-server stuff together: `tsc -p . && lite-server`. Take a look at the docs in the link.

Comment: I ran "tsc -p ." successfully, then I ran "lite-server" successfully from the root directory of ngx-tooltip. What is the url I am supposed to access to get to that sample? I am getting Cannot GET whenever I try to access what I think I am supposed to access ("localhost:port/sample/sample1-simple-usage")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you clone the repo, do an `npm install` in the root directory. Then run `tsc -p .` which should use the tsconfig.json to compile all the ts files into JavaScript. Then you should be able to run the sample file in the repo. If the main.ts in the sample directory didn't compile for some reason, try running `tsc` in that directory.

This all assumes you have NodeJS installed.

Comment: Yes, so I ran tsc -p... now what? When I look under the ./sample/sample1-simple-usage directory, I just see the ts and the html file. What do I do next to see that sample in the browser?

Comment: Assuming you did an `npm install` on the root of the cloned repo, after you did a `tsc -p .` you should have a build/es5 directory with the built files. Run `tsc` in the sample directory with the main.ts file, which should then compile that. They you should have everything you need to run the sample, as long as you are able to serve the page--like with lite-server or something.

Comment: So I ran tsc -p . in the root directory, I see the build/es5 you mention (no idea what its relevance is?). I cd into the sample/sample1-simple-usage directory since that has the main.tsc file, then run tsc. I then run "lite-server" in that same directory (I already have that npm installed)... I just see "Loading..." nothing happens. What am I missing?

Comment: When you run lite-server, a browser should open up and server the index.html in that sample directory. If not, try opening a browser and navigating to that page. If it's using the default port, it would be http://localhost:3000/index.html. The importance of the build/es5 directory is that the index.html page you are trying to run references that code near the bottom.

Comment: I've marked your post as correct as you were the closest, though what was missing was that after running those commands, instead of executing the lite server command -within- the checkout directory "ngx-tooltip", it should be executed outside that directory from the parent directory of ngx-tooltip.